# The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'UserProfile'

Tags: flutter, dart

[This is rout file and this code is rout of EditProfilePage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4q7c.png)

[This image is EditProfilePage, This code is required things and facing the error because of this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0e2Tk.png)

I expecting the solution of this related error in flutter technology.

Comment: can you include code-snippet instead of code-image

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a UserProfile instance on `userProfile` and the `onUpdate` is a callback method which return a UserProfile.

So while creating `EditProfilePage` it will be like

```dart
UserProfile myUserProfileInstance  = UserProfile(....);
  EditProfilePage( userProfile: myUserProfileInstance, 
  onUpdate: (value){
   ///receive update value
  }
);
```

Comment: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function(UserProfile)'.Now showing this error

Comment: consider including minimal snippet

Answer (score 0):

You have to watch out for the types
An empty String is not a valid default value for a callback or an Object

You can create default values for your classes, for example:

```
class UserProfile {
  UserProfile({
    required this.name,
    required this.email,
  });

  final String name;
  final String email;

  static UserProfile defaultValue() => UserProfile(
    name: '',
    email: '',
  );
}
```

Now if you have to use a UserProfile defaultValue

```
EditProfilePage(
  userProfile: UserProfile.defaultValue(),
  onUpdate: (value) {}
)
```

For your last comment in the previous answer, did you forget to pass `(value) {}` instead of `''` in the field `onUpdate`?